# Estimation of partial correlations strength after/during Glasso

Tags: partial-correlation

I've been asked to run some estimations of partial correlation using the glasso algorithm. Luckily, now I'm in a situation where my number of data points is not *that* low ($N > 2\times p $), with N the number of data points and p the number of possible partial correlations. For this reason I could compute partial correlations the traditional way, but I'd like to use glasso nonetheless, because I hope that injecting the prior knowledge of sparsity *should* improve estimations. The thing is that I need to compute the actual partial correlations values, I don't need to just estimate which elements are non-zero.

I've run a simulation. I've made a 7x7 partial covariance matrix with 6 non-zero elements outside the diagonal (6 for each triangular part, since it's simmetric). I've inverted it to compute the covariance one and simulated 10k datasets of 50 data points each. I run the glasso algorithm on each dataset at increasing values of $\lambda$ to estimate the partial covariance. With zero regularization or with very small $\lambda$ the average estimation is equal to the true one. But in single datasets most zero-element are estimated to be non-zero. At increasing values, instead, only the true ones are estimated to be non-zero, but their average estimated strenght is greatly reduced. Suppose I choose a $\lambda$ that gives me 12 non-zero elements (the double of the actually non-zero ones). Those partial correlations that should be 0.8 are estimated to be 0.6 or less. And if I go up to estimate only 7 non-zero elements they're even smaller, like 0.3 or so.

Am I missing something in how to interpret glasso results? I haven't found much literature using the computed partial covariance matrix. Most sources just see which elements are non-zero.

Thanks!